# Tableau: How to plot something like - what % of my margin comes from what % of my total products

Tags: tableau-api, pareto-chart

Hello Tableau Experts!

This might be a simple one, but I am stuck. What I want to be able to do is basically a form of pareto curve - So on one axis I want to plot % of total running sum of margin and on the other % of total running sum of number of products. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might know, that you can get the running totals by adding quick table calculations to the measures or dimensions. (With dimensions, you need to right-click -> measure = "count (distinct)".)

The trick then is to edit these quick table calculations. Just add a secondary calculation: "percent of total"

Maybe watching someone do this in a video might help more:
http://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/pareto-charts